# Local Variable 'df' referenced before assignment UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting that error eventhough the name of my function is different from that of my variable inside the function.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', usecols=('Date','Col2','Col3'))

def foo():
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
    df = df.dropna()
    return df
print(foo())
```

Here's the error that I'm getting:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df' referenced before assignment
```

What should i do to resolve the issue?

Comment: try `def foo(df):`

Comment: @S3DEV that's not precisely the issue. The problem is that the compiler has marked `df` as a local variable, and the OP tries to use that local variable before the assignment

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Excellent.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @RichieV it worked. Thank you!